# std::queue destructor is slow as hell, bug?

Tags: c++, performance, queue, destructor

Why is the destructor in `std::queue` extremely slow? look at my example:

```
void test()
{
    int total = 17173512;
    std::queue<int> q;
    for(int i = 0; i < total; i++)
        q.push(i); //Push is very fast.

    std::cout<<"Done"<<std::endl; //Less than a second.
}

test();
std::cout<<"Done"<<std::endl; //This takes several minutes!!
```

The destructor in `std::vector` is very fast...

**UPDATED:**
My compiler/IDE is Visual studio 2012 Visual C++.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int total = 17173512;
    std::queue<int> q;
    for(int i = 0; i < total; i++)
        q.push(i);

    std::cout<<"Done0"<<std::endl; //This takes less than a second.

    while(!q.empty())
        q.pop();

 //This takes less than a second. Memory should be deallocated here!
    std::cout<<"Done1"<<std::endl;

    //Waiting forever, i.e. deallocating(HERE??) memory EXTREMELY SLOWLY.
   //I can see how the memory is being deallocated here in windows task manager!
        return 0;
}
```

With vector:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int total = 17173512;
    std::vector<int> q(total);
    for(int i = 0; i < total; i++)
        q[i] = 2000;

    std::cout<<"Done"<<std::endl;

    return 0; //Extremely fast.
}
```

***UPDATE 2:***

*Everything is solved now! I uninstalled Visual studio 2012 + visual c++. I have installed Visual Studio Community 2015 and everything is much faster and works as expected!*

Comment: Interesting. Could you paste up an entire program that demonstrates this?

Comment: Did you compile with optimizations switched on? Also, which c++ implementation are you using?

Comment: Takes less than a second for me, even with `-O0`.

Comment: you have to give us more info on the compiler/system/implementation and context. Using clang in my 2009 macbook pro and with -O0 I can run your code in 1486 milliseconds which is not at all a lot for a such a huge queue.. with -O3 I get 150 milliseconds.

Comment: Also, you should compare with `std::deque<int>`, which is what the queue will use internally.

Comment: Dunno what the problem is. Seems fine to me [here](http://ideone.com/JSdU1N), and [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4a13af4426bfee7b). Without platform info, I'm afraid this is going to end on the ash heap.

Comment: Is the exact value 17173512 relevant or is that just some arbitrary large number?

Comment: How do you know it is slow? Is it a copy of a homework question?

Comment: My compiler/IDE is Visual studio 2012 Visual C++. There seems to be some serious problems here... I have opened the windows task manager in windows 7 and I can clearly see how the memory is ticking(deallocating) down very SLOWLY...  I't doesn't matter if I place the code directly in the main function or in a seperate function. It takes a very long time before the function returns. molbdnilo: it doesn't matter, more elements results in slower deallocating.. juanchopanza: I have tried std::deque<int> with the push_back function, exactly the same results...

Comment: See my updated question!

Answer (score 2):

I have used this code to measure:

```
int main(){
    auto test = [](){
        auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        int total = 17173512;
        std::queue<int> q;
        for (int i = 0; i < total; i++){
            q.push(i); //Push is very fast.
        }
        auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        return end - start;
    };

    auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    auto pushing_time = test();

    auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto deleting_time = (end - start) - pushing_time;

    std::cout << "Pushing Time:" << pushing_time.count() << '\n';
    std::cout << "Deleting Time:" << deleting_time.count() << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

---

**Environment:**

- Intel i7-4510U @ 2.00 GHz
- Windows 8.1
- MSVS 2013

---

**Results:**

Release Mode, \O2, **Attached** to VS:

> Pushing Time:71403190
>
> Deleting Time:5293067027

Release Mode, \O2, **Not Attached** to VS:

> Pushing Time:3743267
>
> Deleting Time:1741230

So from the results, I am in doubt that you are running it attached to some IDE.

Comment: See my updated question!

Comment: +1 for the measuring effort.  the results are also defavorable on ideone, although not so big as with MSVC2013:  For the queue, deleting Time is 19.011.638 whereas for the vector it is 4.392.646 so roughly 5 times slower.

Comment: And with intel i7 2,9 GHz, win10, and latest MSVC2015 release, it's still 2.457.842 for the queue and 63.422 for the vector. That's 38 times slower. And with linked lists it's 7.829.505

Answer (score 0):

When a vector of n elements gets destroyed, the n elements get destroyed, then meory gets released in 1 operation (contiguous bloc).

For a queue to be destroyed, memory gets released in n operations, and the memory management system must manage these n free blocs (for ex in a linked list). Memory management can therefore significantly impact performance

Comment: `std::queue` uses a `std::deque` by default, which isn't as bad as a linked list. Regardless, several minutes is ridiculous.

Comment: @T.C. that's true.  Taking the measuring code of Humam Helfawi, with MSVC2015 it's definitively worse with linked lists (3 times slower than queues), but queues are 38 times slower to destroy than vectors. I suspect a very bad implementation of memory deallocation

Answer (score 0):

Generally Christophe is right about the container type but here the problem is independent of the container type. we expect that the memory allocation and release to be almost equal.I analyzed the code in MSVC2010 in both debug and release mode. The Analysis showed that the delete operation is more time-consuming than the new operator. it seems that delete operation includes some extra operations but I don't know it precisely.